# handling JPA transactions exceptions

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, exception, transactions

I have 3 EJBs:

the first one is for persistence:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class PersistenceService
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="pc")
    EntityManager em;

    public <T> void create(T entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
    }
}
```

the second one is for business:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class BusinessService implements 
{
    @EJB
    PersistenceService persistenceService;

    public <T> void register (User user) {
            try{
                    // Do some business
                    persistenceService.persist(user);
                    // Do other business
            }catch(Exception e){
                    // log exception
                    throw new BusinessException(e);
            }
      }
}
```

the third one is A web service which calls the business EJB.

the problem is that the business EJB doesn't catch Database exceptions like constraint violation exception thrown by Mysql connector encapsulated in EJB exception. I can handle this exception at the Rest service EJB but not at the business EJB. I think it's related to Transactions.

I am not sure which transactions attributes should be added to Persistence EJB and Business EJB to let me catch these types of Exceptions in the business EJB.

Comment: Why can't you handle Exceptions at Business layers? Do you see any exception?

Comment: because the exception happens in the transaction which is outside the scope of the business method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the displayed behaviour is likely related to transaction boundaries. Your web service (I'm guessing now) is the upper, non-EJB layer and so when you call `BusinessService.register()` the transaction starts just before the call, and ends just before this call returns.

Runtime exceptions happen at commit time, which in your case happens right after the code of the `register()` method ends; hence it's too soon to handle them there.

You have two options, if you really don't want to handle the exceptions in the web service bean:

**One.** Using bean managed transactions in the `BusinessService` bean

```java
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class BusinessService 
{
@EJB
PersistenceService persistenceService;
@Resource
private UserTransaction ut;

public <T> void register (User user) {
        try{
                ut.begin();
                // Do some business
                persistenceService.persist(user);
                // Do other business
                ut.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
                // log exception
                throw new BusinessException(e);
        }
  }
}
```

**Two**. Introducing a non-transactional facade between the web service bean and EJB:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public FacadeBean {

    @EJB private BusinessService businessService;

    public void facadeMethod(User user) {
        try {
            businessService.register(user);
        } 
        // your handling code here
        catch (...) { ... }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing :), think the non transactional layer is better as I still enjoy the container managed transactions.